# Roscd can't find new packages in fuerte

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all. I had ros electric but I need to get fuerte, so I removed electric and installed fuerte. All of my old packages are in ~/workspace/projects and if I type roscd I can navigate to them. But from now I'm not able to create packages and navigate into them.
I've done roscreate-pkg NAME inside my usual directory and then tried with roscd to navigate inside but I'm not able. Keep attention then all my others packages are in the same directory and roscd can see them

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39003/roscd-can%27t-find-new-packages-in-fuerte/) by [endamaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2861/endamaco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [endamaco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2861/endamaco/) on 2012-07-17**:
Sorry, solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In case

```
roscd NAME
```

does work but the command line auto completion is lacking run

```
rospack profile
```

which will update the cache.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2012-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6